# Kingfisher library not installing in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, kingfisher

I had a problem when installing the kingfisher library  I attached all the screenshots of all errors and pod file please see it and guided me how I can used the kingfisher library.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIozx.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQbi.png)

[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd9fp.png)

[error4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnGl4.png)

[error5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AseSw.png)

[error6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K9cg.png)

[error6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6UuT.png)

[Pod file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIY95.png)

Comment: Please post text as text and not as images, which can't be searched, copied/pasted, read by screen readers, etc

Comment: I vote to close this question, because pictures of text are not a suitable way of providing debugging info. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling the JSONParser 767 error led me to this page: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9694

It suggests to run the following in the terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/
pod install
```

Comments suggest that this reliably solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to reinstall everything

```
rm -rf /Pods /Podfile /Podfile.lock
```

and pod init, install...